# Definite integrals involving $\ln x$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Alright, I have been working on this definite integral for the past couple days now and I can't for the life of me obtain the correct answer. I am not too sure where I am going wrong but I think the $\ln x$ is throwing me off course a bit. Would anyone be able to help me or give me any advice? ANY help is appreciated!

$$\int_1^e (\ln x+1)x^x\,dx$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \int_1^e x^x\left(\ln x+1\right)\ dx $$
Let $u=x^x$, then
$$
\frac{d}{dx}u= \frac{d}{dx}x^x= \frac{d}{dx}e^{ln x^x}= \frac{d}{dx}e^{xln x}= e^{xln x}\left(1ln x+ x\frac{1}{x} \right)= x^x\left(\ln x+1\right)
$$
Which implies that
$$ du= x^x\left(\ln x+1\right) dx$$
Thus
$$ \int_1^{e^e} du=u\bigg|_1^{e^e}=e^e-1 $$

Answer (score 2):

Let $$y=x^x\implies \ln y=x\ln x\\
y'=x^x\{\ln x+1\}\\ \int_1^e x^x\{\ln x+1\}dx=\{x^x\}_1^e$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

$$x^x=e^{x \log(x)}$$

I am sure that you can take from here.

Answer (score 1):

We know that: $$\frac{d}{dx}(x^x) = x^x (\ln x+1) $$ I encourage you to prove that for yourself.

So $$\int_1^e (\ln x+1)x^x\,dx = e^e - 1$$